# Phone doesnt show all text on react-native (Expo)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, text, expo

I have an issue with the output text:

This is just a blank react native code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

[the result on lg-g4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwIp4.jpg)

Insted of showing "Open up App.js to start working on your app!" on the expo app,

I get only "Open up App.js to start working on".

The phone works correctly with any other app (not react native).
react native apps functions works on the phone.
If i comment out the "alignItems: 'center'" from the style it appears correct..
What can i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just try once with whitespaces

```
<Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!                 </Text>
```

Comment: not very practically, it will be weird to use this in all the program.
anyway, it looks like the expo app is broken on the phone..
but thanks!

Comment: this is the solution : https://forums.expo.io/t/text-cut-off-on-oneplus-device/4999/8

its the same\